# How can I get the key:value from a jsonobject in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm doing a POST request, and I have this:

```
...
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
print(json)
```

Which gives this output:

```
{
    code = 400;
}
```

How do I get the value of code (which is a string, in this case "400")?

I tried this:

```
let code = json["code"]
```

But it says **Type 'Any' has no subscript members**

Comment: You need to tell the compiler that `json` is a Dictionary, with `as? [String: Any]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to cast your JSON object to a dictionary:

```
if let json = json as? [String: Any], let code = json["code"] as? Int {
  print(code)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed Int->String because in my case the value is a String